# Gertboard programming atmega328p : can't define "board" to program

Tags: arduino

Using RPi rev B, all software updated (raspbian). I have installed the Arduino IDE software per the instructions of https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gertboard/ .  Originally the download gave errors, but upon subsequent downloads, the errors went away. Software reports that Arduino IDE is installed good.
  I have performed the "Initial Setup of the ATMega", per the instructions of the author of Gertboard ; https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gertboard/  . . .
   I don't get any errors. 
Now, to send a program (sketch) to the Arduino, I need to identify the "board to be programmed."
    I click on the "Tools",  "Board",  so as to identify the type of micro (328P) I would like to program, but there is nothing shown.  The pull down menu is "Tools, Board", which should show a device to be programmed, but there is no further menu. 
   What additional information can I supply to you to help me make further progress with this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite a while since I did this, but `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/boards.txt` should be customised to include sections for the following

```
gert328.name=Gertboard with ATmega328 (GPIO)
```

Comment: You are correct and problem solved. I had downloaded the boards.txt file. However, in moving the file to the folder you show, I omitted a dot (period) at the end of the mv (move) command  $ sudo mv /tmp/boards.txt .  -  also, the programmers.txt needs to be in same folder.  Hat Tip to you.